# Как сделать так чтобы анимация css началась после нажатия кнопки?

Tags: html, css, html5, css-animation

Я верстаю сайт на HTML, CSS и я сделал CSS анимацию, только мне надо сделать чтобы только после нажатия на кнопку(id="show") и я не знаю как єто сделать....

Comment: добавляй класс с анимацией элементу по клику

Comment: Я извиняюсь, но я не очень разбираюсь в JS... Из за этого не понимаю как это сделать... У меня выщло: `document.getElementById("show").addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("box").className += "animation";`, но оно не работает

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pnway9fv/8/ если интересует именно событие 'submit' , его нужно вешать на форму, не на кнопку.

Comment: Проблема в том что у меня такой код: https://jsfiddle.net/x89j0rhv/8/
И для него оно почему-то не работает

Comment: Нужно установить начальное состояние (высоту) полосок и после клика добавлять класс, который уже будет запускать анимацию https://jsfiddle.net/jsh28m7o/1/

Comment: ОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБО! А то я уже голову ломал как сделать